# iPhone - how to be notified of call completion

Tags: iphone, notifications, call

I'm developing an application that needs to take action on completed phone calls, preferably right after the call ends but minimally once per day.

I've read up on the new CoreTelphony framework, and it seems I can get call events if my app is active, but I don't see how to launch/wake my app when a call ends if my app is not the foreground app.  I also don't see how any of the new pseudo-background "modes" would allow my app to listen for these events in the background.  Do any of you know how this might be done?

If post-call processing isn't possible, then I'd like to figure out a way to automatically wake my app up once per day, pull all of the call events since the last wakeup, and process them.  I know how I might do this with Push or Local notifications, but my understanding is that those require user action to continue; in this case, I just want the processing to happen automatically.  Is there a mechanism that would enable this?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't launch your app without user interaction. 
Push / Local notifications aren't for this kind of thing, they're for letting the user know about event.

On a non-jailbroken device there is no way to do what you want to do.